# Want to Implement autocomplete function in my ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have class named`clsUtilities` and stored procedure named `PhoneBook_SearchCustomers`. I want to take `FName` and its respective `Id`. My `DataTable` has both `Id` and `FName`. Now want to convert `DataTable` that into list.  `List<object> ids = (from row in ss.AsEnumerable() select row["FName"]).ToList();`. I do not have an idea how to get`Id` into the same line so that i can pass this into my JavaScript.

My `clsUtilities` class

```
 public DataSet CreateCommandwithParams(string queryString, SqlParameter[] prms)
        {
            string mConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestConnection"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(mConnString))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                if (prms != null)
                {
                    foreach (SqlParameter p in prms)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
                    }
                }
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                conn.Open();
                da.Fill(ds);
                return ds;
            }

        }
```

My Home Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult AutoComplete(string prefix)
        {
            clsUtilities cUtils = new clsUtilities();
            DataSet ds;
            SqlParameter[] prms = new SqlParameter[1];
            string sSQLName;
            sSQLName = " PhoneBook_SearchCustomers @FName";
            prms[0] = new SqlParameter("@FName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            prms[0].Value = prefix;
            ds = cUtils.CreateCommandwithParams(sSQLName, prms);
           DataTable ss = ds.Tables[0];
           List<object> ids = (from row in ss.AsEnumerable() select row["FName"]).ToList();
           return Json(ids);

      }
```

My JavaScript

```
 $(function () {
        $("#txtCustomer").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
               // debugger;
                    $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/AutoComplete/',
                    data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ prefix: request.term, count: 20 }),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                           debugger;
                           return item;

                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            },

            select: function (e, i) {
                debugger;
                $("#hfCustomer").val(i.item.val);
            },
            minLength: 1
        });
});
```

Please guide me how to get `val` value from controller. Now val is showing undefined. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't stringify JSON data before sending because you already precise `dataType` :

```
$("#name").autocomplete({
      source :function( request, response ) {
          $.ajax({
                  url: "/Home/AutoComplete/",
                  dataType: "json",
                  data: {
                      prefix: request.term
               },
               success: function(data) {
                   response($.map(data, function(item) {
                       return {
                           label : item.Value,
                           key: item.Key
                   };
               }));
             }
         });
     },
     select: function (event, ui) {
         $("#hfCustomer").val(ui.item.label);
         $("#hfCustomer").attr("id", ui.item.key);
         return false;
     }
});
```

And then on server side you can send datas (id and value) like :

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AutoComplete(string prefix)
{
    clsUtilities cUtils = new clsUtilities();
    DataSet ds;
    SqlParameter[] prms = new SqlParameter[1];
    string sSQLName;
    sSQLName = " PhoneBook_SearchCustomers @FName";
    prms[0] = new SqlParameter("@FName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    prms[0].Value = prefix;
    ds = cUtils.CreateCommandwithParams(sSQLName, prms);
    DataTable ss = ds.Tables[0];
    List<KeyValuePair<string, string> results = ss.Select(p=>new KeyValuePair<int, string>(int.Parse(p["FId"]), p["FName"]).ToList();
    return Json(results);
}
```

Comment: the POST method accepts only one parameter `public JsonResult AutoComplete(string prefix)` either the method should be changed else this would not work

Comment: @GGO, Thank you for your answer. But i have to get Id from Controller like the way i got FName. I do not have an idea how to get it. Please suggest me.

Comment: @Niladri, I think the only problem is to get Id from database. This code gives me FName and returns FName. But I want to return FName and Id in return Json(ids).

Comment: @GGO, Thank you so much. I appreciate your time and help.

Comment: @GGO, I am trying your code but getting following error: cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type. Please guide me. Thank you.

Comment: @GGO, I have already declared using System.Linq; Error is showing in this line:  p => new { Label = p["FName"], Value = p["FId"] }. As i am not using entity framework so can't write using System.Data.Entity in my context. Is there any other way to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I changed JsonResult Autocomplete function like this and it worked for me now.

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult AutoComplete(string prefix)
        {
            clsUtilities cUtils = new clsUtilities();
            DataSet ds;
            SqlParameter[] prms = new SqlParameter[1];
            string sSQLName;
            sSQLName = " PhoneBook_SearchCustomers @FName";
            prms[0] = new SqlParameter("@FName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            prms[0].Value = prefix;
            ds = cUtils.CreateCommandwithParams(sSQLName, prms);
            DataTable ss = ds.Tables[0];
            List<Test> phoneBookList = new List<Test>();
            phoneBookList = (from DataRow dr in ss.Rows
                           select new Test()
                           {
                               FName = dr["FName"].ToString(),
                               Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Id"])

                           }).ToList();
            return Json(phoneBookList);
        }
```

And in JavaScript, few changes into Success and Select:

```
 $(function () {
        $("#txtCustomer").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/Home/AutoComplete/',
                        data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                           //debugger;
                            return {
                               value: item.FName,
                               id: item.Id
                            };
                   }))
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                //debugger;
                $("#hfCustomer").val(ui.item.value);
                $("#hfCustomer").val(ui.item.id);
            },
            minLength: 1
        });
});
```

Comment: It's not normal that you have to use a temporary `Test` class.My example  sould work. Otherwise you can use KeyValuePair. I update my answer with this, but if it does not suit you it's preferable you edit my answer instead of adding another almost duplicate answer. it's more clear for visitor

Comment: @GGO, Thank you for your input. I have made few changes in autocomplete function and it worked for me. So i thought its better to put it here so that other can get benefited from it if they stuck in similar situation.

Comment: Why unsolved my answer ? KeyValuePair is a better way, and your solution is a duplicate of mine...